# Show records from tomorrow and within 30 days using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date

[image][image]I have 2 DE, Meeting and subscriber. I want to show records dynamically in email
I used `LookupOrderedRows()` to fetch records, now i want to show only 1st record (meeting), which starts from tomorrow and within next 30 days. Below is my code. Unfortunately I'm unable to fetch records from tomorrow.  It is showing yesterday's records only.

```
%%[  
var @rs, @row, @cntr,@lastdate,@today,@tomo
SET @today = Now()
SET @tomo = DateAdd(@today,"1","D")
SET @rs = LookupOrderedRows("InfoMeeting_tst",1,"MeetingDate Asc","info_saleoffice",[SalesOffice],"MeetingType","off")
SET @Mdate = FIELD(ROW(@rs,1), "MeetingDate")

IF DateDiff(@Mdate,@tomo, "D") > 1 THEN

    for @cntr = 1 to RowCount(@rs) do

        SET @row = Row(@rs, @cntr)

        ]%%

        <br>%%=Field(@row, "MeetingDate")=%%
        <br>%%=Field(@row, "MeetingStartTime")=%%
        <br>%%=Field(@row, "City")=%%
        <br>%%=Field(@row, "info_saleoffice")=%%
        <br>%%=Field(@row, "Product")=%%
        <br>@tomo: %%=v(@tomo)=%%

        %%[ 

    next @cntr
%%[ELSE]%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Is this email sent as a realtime trigger or as part of a batch?

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample data from `InfoMeeting_tst`

Comment: Hi Adam,   I have two DE namely Meeting(InfoMeeting_tst) and subscriber, i am using subscriber table for sending email(which has dynamic content, about meeting details). while lookuporderrow() i should show meeting which happening from tomorrow to next 30 days.

Comment: Hi Andrew, i guess this is realtime trigger because i am running Journey campaign, in that i am using these emails.  meeting details are added manually to meeting table. i am fetching records on  2 conditions salesofficecode and meetingtype, when this matchs, i should show meeting details, which are starts from tomorrow and whithin 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're checking the meeting date outside of the `for-loop`.  Here's what I would do:

```
%%[
var @rs, @row, @i, @today, @tomorrow, @numRowsToReturn, @diff, @em
SET @today = Now()
SET @tomorrow = DateAdd(@today,"1","D")
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* all with a limit of 2000 */
set @em = "aspriggs@degdigital.com"
SET @rs = LookupOrderedRows("TestDataExtension",@numRowsToReturn,"MeetingDate Asc","emailAddress",@em)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rs)
output(concat("<br>@rowCount: ",@rowCount))
output(concat("<br>@tomorrow: ",@tomorrow, "<br>"))

if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        SET @row = Row(@rs, @i)
        SET @meetingDate = field(@row, "MeetingDate")
        set @diff = DateDiff(@tomorrow, @meetingDate, "D")

        output(concat("<br>",@i,": @MeetingDate: ",@MeetingDate))
        output(concat(", @diff: ", @diff ))

        IF @diff >= 1 THEN

            ]%%

            , Qualified: %%=v(@meetingDate)=%%

            %%[

        endif

    next @i
else
    output(concat("<br>no matching rows"))
endif
]%%
```

**Output**

```
@rowCount: 24
@tomorrow: 6/29/2017 8:16:44 AM

1: @MeetingDate: 6/28/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: -1
2: @MeetingDate: 6/29/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 0
3: @MeetingDate: 6/30/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 1 , Qualified: 6/30/2017 12:00:00 AM 
4: @MeetingDate: 7/1/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 2 , Qualified: 7/1/2017 12:00:00 AM 
5: @MeetingDate: 7/2/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 3 , Qualified: 7/2/2017 12:00:00 AM 
6: @MeetingDate: 7/3/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 4 , Qualified: 7/3/2017 12:00:00 AM 
7: @MeetingDate: 7/4/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 5 , Qualified: 7/4/2017 12:00:00 AM 
8: @MeetingDate: 7/5/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 6 , Qualified: 7/5/2017 12:00:00 AM 
9: @MeetingDate: 7/6/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 7 , Qualified: 7/6/2017 12:00:00 AM 
10: @MeetingDate: 7/7/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 8 , Qualified: 7/7/2017 12:00:00 AM 
11: @MeetingDate: 7/8/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 9 , Qualified: 7/8/2017 12:00:00 AM 
12: @MeetingDate: 7/9/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 10 , Qualified: 7/9/2017 12:00:00 AM 
13: @MeetingDate: 7/10/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 11 , Qualified: 7/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 
14: @MeetingDate: 7/11/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 12 , Qualified: 7/11/2017 12:00:00 AM 
15: @MeetingDate: 7/12/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 13 , Qualified: 7/12/2017 12:00:00 AM 
16: @MeetingDate: 7/13/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 14 , Qualified: 7/13/2017 12:00:00 AM 
17: @MeetingDate: 7/14/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 15 , Qualified: 7/14/2017 12:00:00 AM 
18: @MeetingDate: 7/15/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 16 , Qualified: 7/15/2017 12:00:00 AM 
19: @MeetingDate: 7/16/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 17 , Qualified: 7/16/2017 12:00:00 AM 
20: @MeetingDate: 7/17/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 18 , Qualified: 7/17/2017 12:00:00 AM 
21: @MeetingDate: 7/18/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 19 , Qualified: 7/18/2017 12:00:00 AM 
22: @MeetingDate: 7/19/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 20 , Qualified: 7/19/2017 12:00:00 AM 
23: @MeetingDate: 7/20/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 21 , Qualified: 7/20/2017 12:00:00 AM 
24: @MeetingDate: 7/21/2017 12:00:00 AM, @diff: 22 , Qualified: 7/21/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Adam, i have copy paste same code, again it is showing MeetingDate: 5/20/2017 12:00:00 AM . my logic is it should not show previous meeting details, it should show only meeting details from tomorrow till next 30 days. eg:- in my table record dated Saturday, July 01, 2017 12:00 AM(last but one record). any suggestion??

Comment: I've updated my example.  You were only returning a single row from your `lookupOrderedRows()` function.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response Adam , good thing is your code is working fine but one query  How can i show only 1st matching record here? that is (3rd record) where i have to change the code?

Comment: Just change the criteria on this line `IF @diff >= 1 THEN`.  You're going to have to iterate through all of the rows no matter what.  You can use the conditional to limit the output.

Comment: what type of condition i should give to limit the output to 1st matching row? can you suggest? i tried giving 1 in lookuporderrow() but no success.

Comment: In the output above, what row is the "1st matching row" according to your requirements?

Comment: this is the row 3: MeetingDate: 6/30/2017 12:00:00 AM, diff: 1 , Qualified: 6/30/2017 12:00:00 AM,  i want to print only this row no previous rows.

Comment: Adam, do you have update any update for me. Thanks

Comment: I don't really know what else I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Your challenge is going to be that LookupOrderedRows doesn't allow you to do any relative comparisons... "MeetingDate > getdate()", for example.

So, hence my question around the nature of the send... realtime or batch?  Your LookupOrderRows by "MeetingDate ASC" will return meeting dates in the past. You'd need to either populate your "InfoMeeting_tst" data extension through a frequently running automation to ensure that only future meetings are in there or skip records that are before @tomo by using an IF statement inside your loop to evaluate @tomo against the record's MeetingDate. Maybe best would be to pre-process your data, so that you know subscribers you're sending to have dates in the future you want to communicate.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it is a Realtime send. as you suggested Automation(Query) to populate only tomorrows meeting, its would be a good idea. and about checking in if condition, i tried all type of conditions,  dont know whats wrong with it, still it is showing records from yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution, for tomorrow to 30 days rule written a query and everything is working good. Thank you for Adam and Andrew.

```
%%[
SET @rs1 = LookupRows("test_journey_audience_NEW","MarketCode",'PLW')
set @rowCount1 = rowcount(@rs1)
if @rowCount1 > 0 then
    SET @row = Row(@rs1,1)
    SET @AOffice1 = field(@row,"Assignedsaleoffice")
endif

if Empty(@AOffice1) then
    SET @rs = LookupOrderedRows("Res_InfoMeeting_tst",1,"MeetingDate Asc","info_saleoffice",[SalesOffice],"MeetingType","off")
else
    Set @rs = LookupOrderedRows("Res_InfoMeeting_tst",1,"MeetingDate Asc","info_saleoffice",[Assignedsaleoffice],"MeetingType","off") 
Endif 

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rs)

if @rowCount > 0 then
    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
        SET @row = Row(@rs,@i)
        SET @meetingDate = field(@row,"MeetingDate")
        if(@meetingDate > Now() and ) Then
        ]%%
        //content to show
        %%[
        endif
    next @i
else
//No content
endif
]%%
```